# cone with vertical angle given by $2\alpha$ , having vertex at origin, and sphere of radius a

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the centre of gravity of the common volume to cone with vertical angle given by $2 \alpha$ , having vertex at origin, and sphere of radius a

Now I can find volume by using

$ \int_{0}^{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{\alpha}\int_{0}^{a} r^2 sin\phi dr d\phi d \theta$ = $\frac{2a^3}{3} (1 - cos\alpha) 2 \pi$.. Not sure about this and how to proceed next ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that by symmetry the centroid must lie on the axis of the cone.

Orient our reference frame so that the axis of symmetry is the $z$-axis (and assuming the majority if not all of the cone lies in $z>0$).  Then your volume is slightly off (I'll leave you to fix that), and
$$
\int_\mathcal{V} z\,\mathrm{d}V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\alpha\int_0^a r\cos\theta\,r^2\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi=2\pi\frac{a^4}{4}\frac{\sin^2 \alpha}{2}
$$
and
$$
\bar{z}=\frac{\int_\mathcal{V} z\,\mathrm{d}V}{\int_\mathcal{V}\,\mathrm{d}V}=\dots
$$

Comment: whats wrong with volume ?I did triple integral again and its right

Comment: You have an extra factor of 2, try $\alpha=\pi$

Comment: that's because of lower part ..ie below xy plane

Comment: There is no lower part.  It is a cone, not a double cone, and your integral is indicating that too.

Comment: how do you know that ?

Comment: Because $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\alpha\int_0^a \dots = \frac{2\pi a^3}{3}(1-\cos\alpha)$, not $\frac{4\pi a^3}{3}(1-\cos\alpha)$.  And if there is a lower part the answer is trivially at the origin by axial symmetry and reflection symmetry, with absolutely no need for calculation.

Comment: that integral computes part bove xy plane..in question they have given cone has vertex at origin , so it can point downwards too..isn't it ?

Comment: Repeat: the integral does not evaluate to $\frac{4\pi a^3}{4}(1-\cos\alpha)$, does it?  If you want to interpret the question as a double cone, that is your choice, but that is not what most people mean by a cone.

Comment: that's because of the limits I put in..iff I use limits for phi from $3\pi/4$ to $\pi$, it would give me same answer

Comment: Obviously you are calculating the triple integral wrong.  End of conversation.

Comment: how is that so ?